# Programmatically distinguishing S3 and S4 objects in R

Tags: r, object, r-s4

If given an object `x`, is there a way to classify whether or not it is `S3` or `S4` (or "other")?  I have looked at `is.object()` and `isS4()`, and can identify that something is an object (or not) and that it is an S4 object (or not).  However, it doesn't seem to me that S3 objects are the complement of all objects that are not S4 objects.

Therefore, how can these assignments be done programmatically?

Here is an example of something that bugs me, taken from the help for `is.object()`:

```
a = as.factor(1:3)
is.object(a)  # TRUE
isS4(a) # FALSE
```

Does that mean that `a` is an `S3` object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it is an object and is not an S4 then it is an S3:

```
is.object(foo) & !isS4(foo)
```

`is.object` checks for some magic OBJECT bit that gets set when the thing has a class attribute, so its essentially a fast way of doing `any(names(attributes(foo))=="class")`, which is what defines an S3 object.

Comment: Well that pretty much answers it.  :)

Comment: I now think there should be an `isS3` along the lines of what you suggest with `any...`.  As it is, basing an assignment on the logical operation `(A & !B)` doesn't allow for a `C` that is pairwise mutually exclusive with each of `A` and `B` (e.g. some future "S5" class that is neither S3 nor S4).  For now, this works, but I feel like I'm walking toward a Y2K-type bug.  :(